# Glossaries description with easylist

Tags: glossaries, easylist

I'm trying to use `easylist` in the description of my `glossaries` entries. However,  the list `easylist` isn't formatting. Does anyone know how to get this to work? I've tried using the `\Activate` and `\Deactivate` commands and that hasn't helped.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}

\setglossarystyle{treegroup}

\newcommand{\bel}{\begin{easylist}[enumerate]}
\newcommand{\eel}{\end{easylist}}

\setglossarystyle{treegroup}

\longnewglossaryentry{entry:enum}{
    name={enumerated entry},
}{% description
This is how I want the entries to look, but I want to use \texttt{easylist} instead of \texttt{enumerate}.
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
        stuff 1
    \item
        stuff 2
    \item
        stuff 3
\end{enumerate}
}

\longnewglossaryentry{entry:easy}{
    name={easylist entry},
}{% description
This entry should look like \gls{entry:enum}.
\bel
@ stuff 1
@ stuff 2
@ stuff 3
\eel
}

\begin{document}

This is my \gls{entry:enum}. This is an \gls{entry:easy}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, with `\Activate` in the preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[at]{easylist}
\usepackage{glossaries}


\newcommand{\bel}{\begin{easylist}[enumerate]}
\newcommand{\eel}{\end{easylist}}

\setglossarystyle{treegroup}

\Activate
\makeglossaries


\longnewglossaryentry{entry:enum}{
    name={enumerated entry},
}{% description
  This is how I want the entries to look, but I want to use \texttt{easylist} instead of \texttt{enumerate}.
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item
    stuff 1
  \item
    stuff 2
  \item
    stuff 3
\end{enumerate}
}

\longnewglossaryentry{entry:easy}{%
  name={easylist entry}
}{%
  This entry should look like \gls{entry:enum}.
  \begin{easylist}[enumerate]
    @ stuff 1
    @ stuff 2
    @ stuff 3
  \end{easylist}
}

\Deactivate

\begin{document}

This is my \gls{entry:enum}. This is an \gls{entry:easy}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @ChistianHupfer
Any idea if issuing `\Activate` in the preamble will cause problems elsewhere or have any other (un)expected side effects?

Comment: @blalterman: I rarely used `easylist` (rarely means effectively: never ;-)), so I can't answer this.

Comment: Fair enough. I added a note to my initial entry with a slight change that allows it to work and issues a `\Deactivate` that _I wold think_ will prevent `\Activate` from carrying too far forward and have edited your answer to include that line.